# How to sum after count the data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have a problem where the output did not sum for 'neu' sentiment. The first 'neu' is from tablea, while
the second is from tableb. Plz help me.
I have this table in mysql:

**Table a**

```
sentid  |   eventid  |  a  |   sentiment  |
-------------------------------------------
1       |    10      | yes |   pos        |
2       |    10      | so  |   neu        |
3       |    11      | me  |   neu        |
4       |    11      | luv |   pos        |
5       |    11      | so  |   neu        |
```

**Table b**

```
 bid    |   eventid  |  b  |   sentiment  |
-------------------------------------------
1       |    11      | hee |   pos        |
2       |    11      | yup |   neu        |
3       |    10      | so  |   neu        |
4       |    10      | ha  |   neu        |
5       |    10      | no  |   neu        |
```

**The output that I got**

```
eventid  |  sentiment   | cnt |
-------------------------------
 10      |   pos        | 1   |
 10      |   neu        | 1   |  #from tablea
 10      |   neu        | 3   |  #from tableb
```

**Desired output**

```
eventid  |  sentiment   | cnt |
-------------------------------
 10      |   pos        | 1   |
 10      |   neu        | 4   |
```

**My code:**

```
select id,sentiment,count(*) as cnt from tablea WHERE id=10 group by sentiment 
union all 
select id,sentiment,count(*) as cnt from tableb WHERE id=10 group by sentiment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNION first, aggregate then.

```
select eventid, sentiment, count(*) as cnt
from
(
  select eventid, sentiment from tablea
  union all
  select eventid, sentiment from tableb
) unioned
group by eventid, sentiment
order by eventid, sentiment;
```

If you want to do this for one `eventid` only, then place `where eventid = 10` after `from tablea` and `from tableb`. You could instead place it once before `group by`, but this may be slower.

Answer (score 2):

You should union first, then aggregate:

```
SELECT
    eventid,
    sentiment,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT eventid, sentiment FROM tablea
    UNION ALL
    SELECT eventid, sentiment FROM tableb
) t
-- WHERE eventid = 10     -- optional
GROUP BY
    eventid,
    sentiment;
```